# Symfony Webpack/Encore processing unreferenced source images

Tags: symfony, webpack, twig, assets, webpack-encore

I am attempting to get Webpack to process and copy all the image files in `src` folder and output them to the `build` folder using ‘image-webpack-loader`.

As far as I understand, Webpack will only do this with images referenced in CSS/SASS/LESS or an entry point.

I am working on a Symfony project and have many references in twig templates, which are obviously ignored.

Any idea how I could make this happen without the addition of a build tool or making a duplicate reference file for every image that I include in a project template?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `s` subdirectory under web root:

   **Symfony 3:**

   ```
   web/s
   ```

   **Symfony 4 & 5:**

   ```
   public/s
   ```
2. Configure your new subdomain:

   **Symfony 3:** (`app/config/config.yml`)

   ```
   framework:
       assets:
           base_urls:
               - '%protocol%://s.%host%'
   ```

   **Symfony 4 & 5:** (`config/packages/assets.yaml`)

   ```
   framework:
       assets:
           base_urls:
               - '%protocol%://s.%host%'
   ```

   *Note:*

   1. `%protocol%` is either `http` or `https` accoring to you environment
   2. `%host%` is your host, maybe `example.com` or something.
3. Configure Webpack (`webpack.config.js`)

   **Symfony 3:**

   ```
   var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

   Encore
       // ...
       .setOutputPath('./web/s/build/')
       .setPublicPath('/build')
       .setManifestKeyPrefix('build')
       .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
       // ...
   ;

   module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
   ```

   **Symfony 4 & 5:**

   ```
   var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

   Encore
       // ...
       .setOutputPath('./public/s/build/')
       .setPublicPath('/build')
       .setManifestKeyPrefix('build')
       .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
       // ...
   ;

   module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
   ```
4. Put all your images inside `/web/s` or `/public/s` according to your Symfony version.
5. Inside your Twig views, access them like below:

   ```
   <img src="{{ asset('photo.jpg') }}" alt="Photo"/>
   ```
6. Accept and hit upvote on this cool answer!

Answer (score 0):

In `webpack.config.js`, you could add `.copyFiles()` to the Encore object.  This will take an object with "from", and "to" keys, with a couple of wildcards.

Here is an example:

```
.copyFiles({
    from: 'src',
    to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]'
})
```